# How does Fate as per god's will and a persons amaal exist together?

Tags: islamic-philosophy, qadar

Consider these two points:

1. Even if a small particle moves, it only because ALLAH wants it  so
   as per conclusion ALLAH has written a man's fate , and whatever the
   man does is written by ALLAH.
2. Whatever a man does, good or bad, his Amaal is calculated by that
   and thus he/she goes to hell or heaven.

So if we are bound to do whatever is written in our fate which is written by ALLAH,
then how come one goes to hell or heaven, as he/she was just doing what ALLAH written in his/her fate?

I had this discussion and I am falling short for proper logic.  I am looking for an answer with reasoning and references to back it up.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly the two points are completely disconnected: A 'thing' and a 'human' are two different topics. It is a comparison as if you wrote a piece of code on a web application and someone comes and asks why is this optical drive not working when I hit print on the web page.

Only humans and no other species (living) have the ability to choose between right and wrong. One might argue that an animal say dog can choose, indeed a dog might love it's owner but when the owner holds a gun to shoot someone, a dog cannot decide if it is right or wrong, or when the owner wrestles with other person, the dog will inherently try to help the owner regardless of who is right or wrong.

Coming to the point of even an atom does not move without the permission of Allah, yes, it is like a program that Allah swt wrote with hardcoded values. From a thing to all living things except humans are pre-programmed with hardcoded values. The functions are different for each but every single one of them has fixed attributes.

Humans are dynamic. They have the ability to choose between right and wrong. There are morals, ethics and rules that govern the human society.

This is what Prophet Mohammed sws has to say about it and there cannot be a better explanation:

> All reported: We were in a funeral in the graveyard of Gharqad that
>   Allah's Messenger (may peace be upon him) came to us and we sat around
>   him. He had a stick with him. He lowered his head and began to scratch
>   the earth with his stick, and then raid: There is not one amongst you
>   whom a scat in Paradise or Hell has not been allotted and about whom
>   it has not been written down whether he would be an evil person or a
>   blessed person. A person said: Allah's Messenger, should we not then
>   depend npon our destiny and abandon our deeds? Thereupon he said: Acts
>   of everyone will be facilitated in, that which has been created for
>   him so that whoever belongs to the com. pany of the blessed will have
>   good works made easier for himand whoever belongs to the unfortunate
>   ones will have evil acts made easier for him. He then recited this
>   verse (from the Qur'an):" Then, who gives to the needy and
>   guardsagainst evil and accepts the excellent (the truth of Islam and
>   the path of righteousness it prescribes), We shall make easy for him
>   the easy end and who is miserly and considers himself above need, We
>   shall make easy for him the dificult end". (XCii. 5-10).
>   -Sahih Muslim Book 033, Number 6398:

Another good read: [Is man’s fate pre-destined or does he have freedom of will?](http://islamqa.info/en/20806)

And Allah knows best.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing happens out of the control of Allah S.W.T but certain things are left on choice of the doer. Not all that Allah S.W.T wants happens due to this, for instance Allah S.W.T doesn't want us to sin, but we still do because we are allowed to make choices. What choices we will make is written, but this doesn't mean we are *bound* to make them.

**For example**, If you are a 100% certain that a student will fail an exam, and you write it down, it doesn't mean that the student was forced to fail and deprived of free will. Allah S.W.T is a 100% certain about everything.

I hope it makes sense (it does in my head)

Comment: how can we have the power to perform something which Allah doesnt wants us to do , i m sorry ,but your answer is not strong on logic or reference

Comment: We cannot change something if He orders it to happen in some specific way, but not every action is ordered to happen in a specific way, some of them are ordered to happen as chosen by us. If we make the choice which Allah S.W.T knows to be bad, then surely He doesn't *want* it to happen, but allows it anyway. The domains of what He wants and what He allows are different. Sometimes actions are allowed even if He doesn't want them because we choose them that way. If those choices are evil, they are marked as sins.
The choice we will make is already written because Allah S.W.T knows it already.